# Understanding the proof that the Euclidean and square metric induce the same topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand the intuition behind the proof that the square and Euclidean metric induce the same topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I'll call these metrics $d_{\infty}$ and $d_E$, respectively. I didn't have any trouble proving that
$$
d_{\infty} (p,q) \leq d_E (p,q) \leq \sqrt{n} d_{\infty} (p,q).
$$
I know, from having seen this problem done, that I need to prove
$$
B^{\infty}_{\frac{r}{\sqrt{n}}} (x) \subset B^E_r (x) \subset B^{\infty}_r (x).
$$
I know how to prove this, but I don't know how I would've come up with this. The hint in the problem is to draw a picture for the next step. In the plane, open balls in the Euclidean metric are open disks and open balls in the square metric are open squares. I know from elementary geometry that the diameter of a circle inscribed in a square is equal to the side length of the square. For a square inscribed in a circle, I know that the diameter of the circle is the length of the diagonal of the square. So if the circle has radius $r$, the diagonal of the square has length $r$, so the side length of the square is $\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}$ by the rules for 45-45-90 triangles.

How do I relate this to open balls in the square metric? I don't know precisely how, if at all, the side length of a square relates to the radius of the open ball.

Comment: Forget the geometry, it's topology!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to draw anything. Take the inequalities as given and use definitions.

E.g. let $y \in B^\infty_{\frac{r}{\sqrt n}}$. This means that $d_\infty(x,y) < \frac{r}{\sqrt n}$. So $$d_E(x,y) \le \sqrt{n}d_\infty(x,y) < \sqrt{n} \cdot \frac{r}{\sqrt n} = r$$

so that by definition $y \in B^E_r(x)$ and we've shown the inclusion.

The other inclusion goes exactly the same way, using the other inequality.
As soon as you have such a uniform inequality between metrics we get a ball inclusion (going in the other direction) for free. It’s just simple arithmetic and considerations about sides and radii etc don’t need to enter into it. In fact we can prove that any metric induced by a norm on $\Bbb R^n$ is equivalent to the Euclidean metric. There will always be such uniform inequalities as you mentioned and thus inclusions of balls two ways.